# Why does python's open() function mangle my utf-8 files?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, lark-parser

This is a strange one, and it might be due to a python update, because it worked fine yesterday with no changes. Here we go:

I have a program that opens utf-8 files (that use accented characters, etc, not just ansi characters).  When I open the files with `open(file, encoding="utf-8-sig").read()`, the non-ansi characters get mangled, as shown here in my terminal:

[mangled characters when encoding of `open()` is set to `"utf-8-sig"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scXRK.png)

However, when I set the encoding to `"ansi"`, the characters are perfectly normal!

[normal characters with `encoding="ansi"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lNma.png)

This is a complete mystery to me. As said before, this worked fine yesterday. I've checked that the files were indeed utf-8, multiple times. I don't know if the problem is with the open() function, or the print() function when the characters are displayed. in any case, it's strange. The `"ansi"` version would be a solution, but the problem is that it causes problems with [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark), which uses the contents of the opened files.

In the screenshots I gave here, the code is basic:

```
with open(str(GRAMMAR), "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as grammar:
    print(grammar.read())
```

What *could* this problem be caused by?

Comment: Is the output in the screenshots from your terminal? It could be entirely a printing issue and not an issue with the actual strings, especially on Windows. Do you have another way to check?

Comment: You could try putting `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` early in your script and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you reduce the file to a single line that fails, read the file with binary, print the result:  `print(open(file,'rb').read())`, and edit your question to include it?  This will remove ambiguity of the file content and encoding.  `ansi` and `utf-8` are completely different encodings, and if `utf-8` works, the file is encoded in UTF-8.  An "ANSI" encoded file with those characters would raise an exception if read as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machines, Python recognises the name "ansi" as an [alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) for the "mbcs" codec, defined as

> Windows only: Encode the operand according to the ANSI codepage (CP_ACP).

So ansi is a valid encoding, but it isn't the same as ASCII, or UTF-8, hence the apparent mangling.

Answer (score -1):

I just noticed something: `ansi` is not an encoding. The correct name for the encoding would be `ascii`. This means that when I typed `encoding="ansi"`, python ignored the encoding I  asked it to set and read the file as its default encoding, which is normally utf-8. This does not explain why it doesn't work with `utf-8-sig` or why Lark is screaming at me, but this is specific to my case. So for future readers of this questions, check 2 things:

1. If you want to use ascii, type `ascii`, not `ansi`.
2. Stick with the defaults.